# CodeIgniter+Bootstrap - Convert HTML to PDF

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, twitter-bootstrap

Before you say it's a duplicate of another question, please read on.

*My development environment is :*

- CodeIgniter
- Twitter Bootstrap

*What I need :*

- To be able to convert a piece of HTML code (or a complete webpage for that matter), **exactly** as it appears as a PDF.

*Hints :*

- I know about domPDF (a common solution, with [a helper already available](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf) for CodeIgniter users), and I've used it in the past; the thing is it does NOT support real conversion (if I have to convert all my bootstrap css to tables, then it's close to useless).
- I'm thinking of using some terminal utility (triggered via ajax?), like [wkHtmlToPdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

---

What would **you** suggest?

Comment: I'd go with wkHtmlToPdf. it has php extension as well. There is not a perfect PDF library in php as far as I know

Comment: @mask8 Please have a look at my other comment at Raidenace's answer. Could there be a workaround in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully used wkHtmltoPdf in the past to convert HTML pages to PDF. One thing of caution however is to check and if necessary strip out javascript in the HTML pages, because from time to time, I have found that sometimes they screw up the rendered PDF. Do not worry about pre-written CI helpers, you can easily integrate wkHtmltoPDF as a library in CI

Comment: Hmmm.. Nice to hear some feedback on `wkHtmlToPdf`. However, I just came up with an issue : just uploaded to my server (shared hosting on HostGator), and when I `ssh`ed and tried running it, I came across a "jailshell" error (a.k.a. Restricted shell access). So I suppose php's `eval` wouldn't work either... brilliant... :/

Comment: oh boy :| Mine was a full-blooded server, with root access (belonged to my client), so thankfully I didn't have such issues..brrrr

Comment: OH!!! Just re-re-re-tried it... (even contacted Hostgator's support for the matter - actually discovered the cause myself while on-line :/). And, to my utter disbelief, **it worked**! Yep, it was all *my fault* : I forgot to `chmod +x` the binary... lol (omg, after 15 hours consecutive coding, my head goes like bzzzziiiin....) Thanks anyway! :-)